# View a specific bit of a hex number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am working on a piece of logic that will teach me how bitops and bit manipulation works, and I am trying to view a specific bit of a given hex number. For example f0f0 has the following bit value 1111000011110000. So let's say I am trying to view the i^th bit, let's say for example i choose the 4th position, my logic should return 1. I tried doing it by doing this logic:

```
unsigned int desiredBit = hex & (1 << decimal);
      printf("%x\n", desiredBit);
```

This seems to work any time a bit is 0, but whenever a bit is 1, it spits out a  multiple of 10. I assumed that doing a `<<` would just take me to that position but i guess I was wrong. Any guidance on how to fix my logic?

Comment: Your logic is correct, except that the actual value of desiredBit is not of interest to you, only whether it is zero or not. If you want `desiredBit` to be either 1 or 0, then you must reverse the shift operation again after performing the bitwise-AND (`&`) operation.

Comment: there is nothing like hex number or decimal number in computers (maybe except BCD format). Everything is binary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a multiple of 2 actually, i.e. the "weight" of this particular bit if it is set, 0 otherwise. If you just want to know if it is set or not, check if this weight is something != 0 or not:

Try

```
unsigned int setOrNot = (hex & (1 << decimal)) != 0;
```

Comment: Or `(hex >> decimal) & 1`.

Comment: I believe he's looking for the 4th most significant bit, not the 4th least significant bit.

Comment: that seemed to solve it, but does adding ```!= 0``` solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the numerical value of the number with just that one that bit set, which isn't exactly `1` unless it's the LSB.

For example, with the number `0b11100101`, if you mask out the second-MSB (`0b11100101 & 0b01000000`), the result is `0b01000000` which is 64 in base 10.

If you want the result to be either `1` or `0`, you can perform `!!` on the entire operation, i.e. `printf("%d\n", !!(num1 & num2));` will always either be `1` if the bit was set or `0` if it was not.